# Микитко сын Алексеев о слове "кушать"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Попалось в Ютьюбе его [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxY-9xB4a3s) годичной давности, в котором он говорит, что очень избирательное употребление этого слова основано на неверных стереотипах и предписаниях. Он объясняет, почему, на его взгляд, нормально говорить "я кушаю", опровергает то, что это слово было в широком употреблении только у лакеев и мещан. Он также говорит, что слова *"кушать"* и *"есть"* оба употребляли широко в XIX веке и не было явной склонности к какому-то из них.

Кто что думает по этому поводу? Прав Микитко сын Алексеев? Можно забыть эти предрассудки и спокойно употреблять это слово или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрел отрывками некоторые видео данного автора (я предпочёл бы читать, а не слушать, поэтому не особо углублялся). Искажения фактов, лже-этимологии и т. п. я не заметил (впрочем, он лингвист по образованию и не мне судить о его профессиональных знаниях).

Насчёт его правоты. Он носитель языка и имеет право всеми доступными (законными) способами распространять своё мнение о том, каким должен быть язык. В этом он прав. Если он считает, что язык развивается по каким-то простым причинно-следственным законам и не подвержен влиянию предрассудков, стереотипов, случайностей и пр., тогда он ошибается. Впрочем, вряд ли он так считает, хотя может выбрать себе такой имидж ради раскрутки канала.

Есть сотни (тысячи?) слов, которые выходят или уже вышли из употребления по самым разным причинам. Можно, например, говорить "вы***док" вместо "внебрачный сын", доказывая законность такого слова в литературном языке цитатами Толстого и др. именитых писателей. Но не в каждом кругу поймут такое пренебрежение предрассудками.

Comment: Спасибо! Меня больше интересует, действительно ли предрассудки насчёт слова "кушать" необоснованны. Тогда, если его и правда по ошибке стараются избегать, те, кому оно нравится, могут его свободнее употреблять. Ну а те, кому не нравится, пожалуйста, пусть говорят только "есть". Главное, снять оковы, заставляющие от него удерживаться, если они в самом деле ложные, надуманные.